# Can't Compile using Qt Creator on Windows 7 x64

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, 64-bit

Using a fresh install of Qt Creator, I am unable to compile anything including any of the demo projects, or any of my own. I installed Qt Creator on a fresh install of XP on VMWare and it works and compiles fine. My computer is running Windows 7 x64. When attempting to build one of the demo projects, there are several build errors as seen in this screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/QJUCN.png]

Also, here is a paste of my Compile Output:
http://pastebin.com/xjuJbUEC

It seems like it is using files within ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98’ when it should not be, although I am not too sure. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Check the Qt4 panel in preferences. You probably have something configured wrong there.

Comment: Your screen shot is completely useless, because it doesn't contain any error messages. These are marked with a red blob in the left margin. Scroll down for us, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some mis-configuration in the Qt4 preferences panel. Go to Tools > Options and select Qt4 in the side bar. Select your Qt installation and make sure the MinGW directory points to a valid mingw installation.

Comment: I checked the Qt4 preferences and they seem to be okay. They point to the mingw installation that the Qt Creator setup has created. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/aikvY.png. Also, here is a better screenshot of the build errors: http://i.imgur.com/N9hIe.png

Comment: If you never edited the sample project file and got those errors, my only guess is some environment variables defined for VC is causing qmake to add include paths specific to VC. That in turn cause gcc to include wrong versions of header files. Check your Windows environment variable to see if there's any thing like that.

Comment: That is very well possible. I do also have Visual Studio 6, Visual Studio .NET 2008 and Visual Studio .NET 2010 installed. Here is a screenshot of all my environment variables: http://i.imgur.com/XxHaI.png

Comment: My guess is "include" EV. Try remove it and see if it works. But if that's the problem and your VC installations require it, I don't have a solution then. :(

Comment: Solved. I deleted the 'include' and 'libs' EV's and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.